# Develop Salesforce Commerce Cloud Cartridge Loading Order

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I would like to develop a Salesforce Commerce Cloud Cartridge.
My JS code needs to load before all other JS Code.
What are my possibilities to achieve that? is it even possible to determine when your plugin loads?

I read about the cartridge stack load order,
Base -> Plugin -> LINK -> Custom (default).

I cannot seem to understand, is it possible to develop a Plugin or LINK cartridge? what does it require of me?

Answer (score 0):

In SFCC the cartridge path and the cartridge itself has no influence on the JS code that is delivered to the client. It only defines what files take precedence during code generation on the server-side.

If you want to make sure you plugin code runs first on the client side you would have to either write a wrapper that makes all other scripts wait or add your JS code as dependency to other scripts. I doubt however that you can provide this functionality simply through your cartridge. I think whoever uses the cartridge has to take care of that manually.